# Is there a logic behind the particular unit vector used in calculating slope in multivariable problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A text reads

Find the slope of $z = x^2 +y^2 at (1, 2)$ in the direction of the vector
⟨3, 4⟩.
We first compute the gradient at (1, 2): ∇f = ⟨2x; 2y⟩, which is ⟨2, 4⟩ at (1, 2). A unit vector in the desired direction is $⟨\frac{3}{5}\frac{4}{5}⟩$ and the desired slope is then $⟨2, 4⟩⟨\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}⟩ = 22/5.$

Is there a particular reason the text chose the above unit vector as opposed to a unit vector such as $⟨\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}⟩$?

Where do we use the information that the gradient is going in the direction of the vector (3,4)?

Comment: The vector $\langle \frac35, \frac45 \rangle$ is parallel to $\langle 3,4 \rangle$, but $\langle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \rangle$ is not.  The reason we use $\langle \frac35, \frac45 \rangle$ is because that's the vector you get when you normalize $\langle 3,4 \rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine being at the point $(1,2,5)$ on the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$. You can move up, left, down, side, to side. The tangent at that point is not unique. But if you want to know the slope of the tangent in the direction of the vector $\langle 3,4 \rangle$, then you have specified a unique direction, and hence there must be one answer.

Here the unit vector in the direction of $\langle 3,4 \rangle$ is $\langle \frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5} \rangle$ because $c \langle 3,4 \rangle$ with $c>0$ is in the same direction as $\langle 3,4 \rangle$ and the length of $\langle 3,4 \rangle$ is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5$.

---

Now we derive a formula for the instantaneous   slope in the direction of the unit vector $\langle a,b \rangle$. From the point $(x_0,y_0)$ go a small amount in the direction of $\langle a,b \rangle$ to get to $(x_0+ha,y_0+hb)$ where $h$ is very close to $0$ and represents the distance we go along $\langle a,b \rangle$ from our starting point (it is the fact that $\langle a,b \rangle$ is unit length that allows us to say this). Now the slope per unit along $\langle a,b \rangle$ is,

$$\frac{f(x_0+ha,y_0+hb)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$

We are interested in,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+ha,y_0+hb)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$$

Let $g(h)=f(x_0+ha,y_0+hb)$ notice we want to compute,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=g'(0)$$

To do this we utilize the multivariable chain rule. We are trying to take the derivative of $g(h)=f(x(h),y(h))=f(x_0+ha,y_0+hb)$ with respect to $h$:

$$\frac{d}{dh}f(x(h),y(h))=\frac{dx}{dh}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{dy}{dh}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Using this we get,

$$g'(h)=af_x(x_0+ha,y_0+ha)+bf_y(x_0+ha,y_0+bh)$$

Then letting $h=0$ gives,

$$g'(0)=\langle a,b \rangle \cdot \nabla f(x_0,y_0)$$

Comment: "it is the fact that $\langle a,b \rangle$ is unit length that allows us to say this" - what does "this" refer to? what would happen if it $\langle a,b \rangle$ is not a unit length?

Answer (score 0):

In physics you see this type of problems very often. You calculate a force, then you decompose it into components along directions that make your calculations easier. For example, the force of gravity (which is also derived from a potential, therefore we use gradient) is vertically down, but if I have a particle moving along an inclined plane, we decompose gravity into components along the plane and perpendicular to the plane